# USING Guid as PK in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We import data from servicenow. The incoming keys are `GUID`, however the database is set to use the column as `nvarchar()` nevertheless query times can be extremely slow when joining the sysid columns to other tables (also stored as `nvarchar()` but no drawn relationships).

Unless I do some heavy indexing, most reports run slow or never return any results. I don't want to over index the database and risk running out of space. Is it advisable to convert the `nvarchar` columns to `GUID` in all of the tables? will it break? (loaded question)

Comment: If you're worried about running out of disk from adding an index, I'd say you have more pressing concerns to address. 

If you don't want to worry about the datatype conversion, you might consider using an integer primary key in your Destination tables, and then creating a mapping table of those int PKs to the GUID/NVARCHAR keys coming from the Source.

Comment: You might benefit from learning more about index utilization and tuning. I know this is slightly off-topic from your question, but I think it might help with your extremely slow queries. https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-index-performance-tuning-using-built-in-index-utilization-metrics/

Answer (score 5):

It depends.

Changing the type from nvarchar to GUID should reduce the size of the index underneath the primary key (since you’ll be eliminating the need for UNICODE), but without knowing what other indexes you have in place, it’s tough to gauge the impact on performance.  In general, though, it’s best practice to make your type match your data.

Note that if the PK is clustered (which is the default setting), every subsequent index will include the column. The narrower the clustered index, the narrower the subsequent indexes.  Additionally, clustering on a GUID can lead to heavy fragmentation of ALL indexes (if the GUID is nonsequential). Before you begin making changes, you may want to make sure you have maintenance in place to reduce fragmentation and update statistics as needed.

You may want to see if another column is more appropriate for clustering, even if you leave the PK in place (a date inserted column for example).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will keep this in mind. We have all of our primary keys on all tables as nvarchar. We have some simple queries that never return results. I've started to look at the indexing startegy. But this is a good start and i appreciate your input.

Comment: You referenced no drawn relationships; do you mean you have no FKs?  If that’s the case, then you may look into establishing those as well (after you fix the types and potential fragmentation).